# Palm software that can turn the Palm IR keyboard into a Bluetooth keyboard for PC?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, palm

I had this kooky idea this morning. I love my foldout palm keyboard, but it only speaks IR to my Palm Treo. But it also has a Bluetooth radio so I thought wouldn't it be just keen to have a program that runs on the Treo that reads from the IR the keyboard and exposes it as a Bluetooth keyboard for a PC.

I realize I'm way late to the game because there's so little information about the Palm anymore. I was thinking of writing this software if it wasn't too big of a deal, but I figured I'd see if anybody knew of such a project already  in existence or something like it that I could piggyback off of.

Not even sure if I can get the Palm OS Developers' kit anymore....

Comment: @Stu, if you're looking for the Palm OS SDK and having trouble finding it, you might try looking on eMule or similar services.  People often share obscure or obsolete bits of software on there.

Comment: Could you use a vnc client to connect to the pc? you could network the two over bluetooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I just had the same idea this morning.
I plan to use my old IR keyboard linked with my now-useless Palm Tungsten T5, to make me a brand new (and costless !) bluetooth keyboard for my Android tablet.

I think I can do the project, because I used to make some Palm softwares at the time.

Are you still interested ? If so, I'll keep you informed of my progress.

**Edit :** Well, it's done, and can be downloaded [here](http://www.crocoware.com/?page_id=202) for those who are interested... I will enventually publish it on the market if needed...

Comment: Sure am. That would be awesome.

Comment: Actually, the project is started. I have a first alpha version which is working and almost useable. I will post my progresses on my blog : http://www.crocoware.com/?p=67